# toggle text on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, html, text, toggle

what i would like to do is toggle a text vertically from bottom to top inside a div.

i have managed to do that but only from top to bottom.

any ideas?

here's the code

```
<div id="box1">
<div id="box1text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut placerat purus elit, sit amet dignissim dui elementum in. Nunc elementum tempor nulla quis mollis. Nunc et nibh eu magna pharetra condimentum ac ut felis.Nunc et nibh eu magna pharetra condimentum ac ut felis.Nunc et nibh eu magna pharetra condimentum ac ut felis.
</div>
</div><!--box1 end -->

    #box1 {
        width:340px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        float:left;
    }

    #box1text {
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding:10px 10px;
    text-align:justify;


    }

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#box1text").hover(
    //on mouseover
    function() {
      $(this).animate({ 
        height: '+=150' 
        }, 'slow' 
      );
    },
    //on mouseout
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        height: '-=150px' 
        }, 'slow'
      );
    }
  );

});
```

here's the demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/atseros/YrFaQ/

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are trying to do... ???

Comment: @Shiva It's damn clear, he is able to toggle the text from top to bottom, he wants the reverse effect

Comment: That would be simple, just subtract the height on mouse over and add it on mouse leave(just the opposite math,currently being used in the JS function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pure CSS solution, I've made it from scratch, you can use `display: table-cell;` and use `vertical-align: bottom;` to align the text to the bottom, and than use `transition` for smoothing up.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YrFaQ/5/)

```
div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

div span {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

div:hover span {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `position: relative;` on the container element and than use `position: absolute;` for the child and provide `top`, `bottom` values respectively..

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/YrFaQ/6/)

---

Even if the browser fails to transit the element, still it will toggle the effect but without the smoothness. This will be useful to few users who just use jQuery to achieve such effect, but by using this, you will save `90KB` of library. (But anyways, jQuery FTW)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/YrFaQ/1/

just position your box1text to the bottom of box1. You can do this by giving your box1 container a relative position. this way you can position any child element (box1text) absolute inside the container. Have a look at the css...

```
#box1 {
    width:340px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

#box1text {
    height:50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding:5px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0
}
```